# Bring Matlab uigetfile window to front of all other programs?

Tags: matlab, setfocus

I'm calling a script from another program (Vicon Nexus 2.3). This other program will launch Matlab, then run the script.

The first thing the script does is it calls uigetfile(). However since the Nexus program has the Windows focus, the uigetfile() window appears behind everything. Is there any way to bring it to the front without using the mouse?

I've tried:

```
shg
uistack()
```

But I think the issue here is windows focus, not uistack. Anyone out there know if this is possible?

Comment: Just to make sure, did you try [`uistack`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uistack.html) with the second argument 'top', i.e., `uistack(handle_to_uigetfile_object, 'top')`?

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is bring Matlab to front before opening `uigetfile` dialogue. You can do that e.g. by calling `commandwindow`:

```
commandwindow();
uigetfile();
```

Tested by starting Matlab from command line and overlaying some other windows on top once it is open, but before the code after `pause` is executed:

```
matlab -r "pause(3); commandwindow(); uigetfile();"
```

Comment: This works great for bringing the uigetfile window in front of other Matlab windows +1, however it doesn't work for me when another application has Windows' focus. The code causes the commandwindow icon in the toolbar to flash but it doesn't pop up in front.